How to share a project that needs an API Token withour revealing in GitHub
I have been doing courses for algorithmic trading this week and, as you to connect to an API, it is  required to use an API Token together with the API URL.
The project works good, everything is ok. Nevertheless, I have seen that if you upload an archive and you call it secrets.py, the archive is hidden for the public on GitHub (I´m not sure about this but there should be a way to hide it).
The point is that I need to hide the API Token somewhere in the folder and them upload it, but when you call it secrets.py, what happens is that while calling it such as:
from secrets import API_Token
being API Token:
API_Token = 'stringthataccesstheAPI'
I expected to do all the imports properly but they threw an error due to their internal Script called secrets.py. It does not allow me to import the usual packages as the have the secrets.py file too.
For example, if I do the import above, and then bring this packages:
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

Neither will be imported to the Notebook, because that file is already in the packages.
My solution has been to import the file changing it´s name to api_secrets.py and then, it works, but I don´t know how it will be hidden in GitHub, or how it will work if someone downloads it. This are my first projects with APIs so maybe I haven´t explained something well.

why publish the API token to github at all? Surely whoever is going to use the code should have their own (local) token?

It's always the responsibility of the user to supply an appropriate token. Your code should only have a configuration parameter allowing the user to specify the location of the token at runtime.

Never publish private API keys. Not to github, and not to any other online place. The only time you provide secrets to github is when you're using GitHub actions which need those API keys to perform the action, and GitHub provides a mechanism outside of the git repository proper to store secrets. Even then, take the time to think about whether you can avoid using the API key.
One place where you generally would think you need the API keys but often don't really do is testing. Some APIs, for example, might provide a test key which you can use for getting your tests to pass. In other cases you might be able to mock the APIs for testing.
It's difficult to understand, from your question, what exactly you are trying to do. My best guess is that you're publishing an IPython notebook or similar which has code which relies on an external API. Here, you have two options :

Publish the application to use your API key. When you do so, be aware of what you are doing and why. If the API key ends up being misused and the API provider cancels your access, it's your fault. You can do this sort of thing if you have other controls in place, such as you're publishing only on your local network with people you trust or your notebook is somehow well password protected with a limited number of trusted users. Even then, remember that the API token is generally best kept out of github, and provided to the code in other ways when it is deployed, such as environment variables, command line arguments, or private configuration files. Don't add the API keys to git or any hidden files thereof and think they are protected. They're not.

Write your code to accept the API key. Let the user enter it somewhere near the top of your notebook. This would be preferred way. The way it generally would look in code is :


   ...
   # somewhere at the top
   API_TOKEN = None

   ...
   # where you need the token
   def some_api_using_function():
      if not API_TOKEN:
          raise Exception("Please configure your API Token to use this function")
      # ... actual API using code

(You'll need to modify this to adjust to your notebook format.)
On a related note, remember that git also has the whole history of your repository. If you ever had your keys in git, you should try to remove them. This is somewhat harder to do, but quite possible. If your API key provides access to private information or a resource you're going to pay for, then this is not an optional thing.

There's no need to remove from history. Any exposed token must be rotated - there are bots that scan github 24/7 looking for secrets in well-known formats.

That´s exactly the situation. I´m using the IEX Cloud API. So, if I want someone to just run the code I cannot do it by myself and they should find their own API key?

It depends on who they are and how sensitive your API key is. In any case, putting it on git is generally a bad idea. You can provide it to your code in some other way if you want it functional without the user needing to bother about it. Environment variables is generally an easy way to do this. You could also have the user enter the API key and you can email the key to them.

the github doc literally says

Don't share your personal access token with others. Instead of sharing a personal access token, consider creating a GitHub App.

i dont think there would come a scenario where u would need to share your API token by hardcoding it and thereby exposing it in your repo. for projects like these, anyone who clones the repo or works on it should use their own key regardless. here's a more elaborate answer for your whats and whys.
if you still insist on using your token, maybe check the docs out

Thank you so much! I didn´t know if it could work with another person´s key without sharing it, now I understand much better the idea.
